Docker json file log driver unescape
I am running docker on EC2 and my app is running as a container in this docker.
It produces a log like this:
{"key": "value"}

This is the output from docker logs <container id>. If I check the daemon log of the container from the /var/lib/docker/container/<whateverid>
{"log": {\"key\": \"value\"}}

Is there a way to unescape this in the daemon logs? There is a complex use case which can't be explained for me to use these logs.

When using the JSON log driver, the log file is a collection of JSON objects, one per line. In order to present the JSON output from your container, it must be escaped; otherwise the logfile itself would contain invalid JSON documents.
Since the API, via docker logs, gives you the unescaped output, it's not really clear what the issue is here. You should generally be retrieving logs via the API, not by directly parsing the backing file.
